# Novel series about space colonization and religion by (Star Wars EU author?)

Tags: story-identification, religion, space-colonization

Trying to identify this series I never finished. I'm almost positive it was written by one of the more famous Star Wars EU authors, but I could be wrong about that as I can't find it when looking through their other books. The last novel in this series has to be somewhat recent (last 5 years or so) as the series was not completed when I was reading it.

Anyways, it takes place on another planet/colony with two primary groups of settlers at the start.  Advanced technology allowed the second group to show up at around the same time as the first group. Many of the first group leave the settlement and live in the woods where they eventually fight a rebellion.

Eventually the first group wins the rebellion and at some point are contacted by aliens who share their religion with the humans. I think the humans had to work on some sort of portal/transportation for the aliens as well. This religion gains increasing popularity and eventually leads to conflict in the colony.

The main other thing I remember is in the last book of the series the one of the main characters, a male and I think governor of the colony dies when somebody sets off a bomb in the spaceship or aircraft he is traveling in.